# Sh - how to remove all after selection

Tags: sed, sh, echo, busybox

I'm trying to manipulate a string and the first step is to truncate the variable after a combination, so first I create the var:

```
SERVER_CONFIGURATION_FILE=$(curl some remove url)
```

And now my $SERVER_CONFIGURATION_FILE is something like that

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 192.145.127.237 1194
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0
comp-lzo no

remote-cert-tls server

auth-user-pass
verb 3
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
e685bdaf659a25a200e2b9e39e51ff03
0fc72cf1ce07232bd8b2be5e6c670143
f51e937e670eee09d4f2ea5a6e4e6996
5db852c275351b86fc4ca892d78ae002
d6f70d029bd79c4d1c26cf14e9588033
cf639f8a74809f29f72b9d58f9b8f5fe
fc7938eade40e9fed6cb92184abb2cc1
0eb1a296df243b251df0643d53724cdb
5a92a1d6cb817804c4a9319b57d53be5
80815bcfcb2df55018cc83fc43bc7ff8
2d51f9b88364776ee9d12fc85cc7ea5b
9741c4f598c485316db066d52db4540e
212e1518a9bd4828219e24b20d88f598
a196c9de96012090e333519ae18d3509
9427e7b372d348d352dc4c85e18cd4b9
3f8a56ddb2e64eb67adfc9b337157ff4
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

From here I want to delete all after `<ca>` tag

I tried various way, but every time the result is the same, I don't know what I do wrong

The last I tried is

```
echo "$SERVER_CONFIGURATION_FILE" | sed 's/<c[.\s\S\d\D\w\W]*//'
```

but remove only `<ca` and nothing more and the funny is that under regex101 this regex works

I feel pretty stupid but I can't find what I miss!

Any idea?

Please note that I'm under sh with busybox 1.30

Comment: What is `[.\s\S\d\D\w\W]` supposed to represent? The fact that a regex works in regex101 means exactly that - that the regexp works on a web site named regex101. It certainly doesn't mean it'll work in any given command line UNIX tool.

Comment: Is a try, I don't know way don't go over ca tag, I suppose because there's a new line, so I inserted all possible character

Comment: `.` alone outside of a bracket expression means `any character`.

Comment: I know, but won't works in this case, so I tried different solution, but without success, this's the last one I came up

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't imagine what you mean by `won't work`. I also don't know why you aren't simply using `<ca>`. If you could clarify what you tried, how it failed, what it was you were trying to express, etc. then we could help you.

Comment: Oh hang on, I think I now what's going on. You sed script "won't work" because you want it to work on the whole input stream at once but it's working on it one line at a time and so you were getting (wildly :-)!) creative with the regexp but the regexp was never the problem, it's just that sed processes one line at a time, not a multi-line block. You can solve THAT problem with GNU sed and `-z` or other ways but the simplest solution is to just use `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need sed or awk for that. You can do it directly in the shell like this:

```
SERVER_CONFIGURATION_FILE="${SERVER_CONFIGURATION_FILE%%<ca>*}"
```

(Tested in dash; I assume busybox sh works the same way.)

`${var%%pattern}` expands to the contents of `var`, but with the longest suffix matching the glob pattern `pattern` stripped away.

---

The main problem with your sed attempt is that sed reads input one line at a time, so matches from one line wouldn't affect the other lines. (Also, your regex is slightly crazy and doesn't work like that in sed anyway.)

A working sed solution:

```
sed '/<ca>/{x;q}'
```

Or, perhaps more directly:

```
sed -n '/<ca>/q; p'
```

I.e. do not print by default; if line matches `<ca>`, quit; otherwise print and read the next line.

Comment: Interesting, maybe is better if I don't use awk or sed

Comment: @JormanFranzini It'll probably be slightly faster because it doesn't have to spawn a new process just to cut off parts of a string.

Comment: can also be used to remove single lines? Because the very next step is to search and remove some lines like dev tun and so on

Comment: @JormanFranzini Doesn't look like it. You could do it with bash, but it looks like dash doesn't support general substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '/<ca>/{exit} 1' file
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 192.145.127.237 1194
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0
comp-lzo no

remote-cert-tls server

auth-user-pass
verb 3
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
```

if your text is in a variable or coming from a pipe otherwise then just call it like this:

```
echo "$SERVER_CONFIGURATION_FILE" | awk '/<ca>/{exit} 1'
```

Comment: Yep, exactly, what mean the 1 at the end?

Comment: It's a true code condition so it invokes teh default action of printing the current record. It's an **extremely** common awk idiom - you'll see it all over the place

Comment: I don't know too much about awk, sometimes I use sed or grep, but I see that awk is pretty good in this situation. Many thanks, I'll consider to make more test with awk.

Comment: Perl version: `perl -pe 'exit if /<ca>/'`

Comment: @JormanFranzini when you need to do s/old/new on individual lines use sed. When you need to do `g/re/p` use grep. When it's anything else, just use awk.